# Chart Component C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, charts, bezier, curve

I've managed to draw a bezier curve using Chart Control in C#.NET. However, there is 2 points on the curve that is drawn wrongly. I've tried many ways around that but was unsuccessful.

The highlighted area should not drop below the x-axis, it should be more of a straight line. Any ideas?

Comment: The curves look correct as Bezier curves try to be as 'round' as they can. You will need to add __more__ Points to control their behaviour closer.  I don't quite understand your last question. Also, showing us some code might help..

Comment: I did add more points, but still it would do that at the inflection point. My last question was an error on my part though and fixed it.

Comment: How many points did you add? 3 or 4 won't do. Try 100!

Comment: Also: Adding a few more points to the left and right will help to reduce the swing of the curve. You are using the Spline type of the Chart, right?

Comment: Yes I am. I now trying to add real values to the datapoints and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will go under 0, there is nothing wrong with the chart. As you already mentioned, you are using bezier curves. I suggest you to study those curves a bit to understand how they work. [Wikipedia article about Beziér curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (one of the few helpful articles on wiki :)

If you don't want to go under 0 in your readings you can use the Max() function with 0 as one of its parameters.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the curve from dropping below 0. Is it possible to control that in Bezier curve? I added points at averages x positions to try to control the shape of the curve, but it didn't work. Every time it will drop below 0 at the inflection point.

Answer (score 0):

this chart uses curved line on drawing change the curved line to straight line chart by using "line" chart type